# Tratamento de Erros Python

Tags: python, exceção, try-catch

Estou estudando tratamentos em python e a ideia do meu código e simular dados de rpg.
só que do jeito que eu estou fazendo qualquer coisa que eu digito está sendo válido , o que eu tenho que fazer para que o tratamento só aceite sim ou não ?
eu tentei já com TypeError

```
import random, time
resposta = ""
# 1 ou 4 dados de 0 a 20 numeros cada dado
def dx(x,y) :
    print("\n"+str(x) +"d"+ str(y)+" \n")
    total = 0
    time.sleep(1)
    for x in range(x):
       dado = int(random.randint(1,y))
       total = dado + total
       dado = str(dado)
       print ("Caiu : "+ dado)

    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")   
    print ("~ Total : " + str(total) + " ~" )
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

print("Você deseja jogar um dado?")
resposta = input(resposta)
while resposta == True:
    try :
    #resposta ="y"
        if((resposta == "sim") or (resposta == "yes") or (resposta == "s")or (resposta =="y")) :
           x = random.randint(1,4)
           y = random.randint(4,20)
           dx(x,y)
        elif ((resposta == "nao") or (resposta == "no") or (resposta == "n")):
           print("fim da rodada")
           break
    except: ValueError : print("Responda corretamente (sim, não, yes, no, y ou n)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver este problema seria implementando uma função auxiliar que possui o papel de validar a entrada que o usuário passou.

Segue um exemplo de como pode ser implementada:

```
def ler_sim_ou_nao():
    while True:
        try:
            resposta = input('Deseja jogar um dado?')
            resposta = resposta.lower()
            if resposta == "sim" or resposta == "yes" or resposta == "s" or resposta =="y":
                x = random.randint(1,4)
                y = random.randint(4,20)
                dx(x,y)
                return
            elif resposta == "nao" or resposta == "no" or resposta == "n":
                print("fim da rodada")
                return
            raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Responda corretamente (sim, não, yes, no, y ou n)")
```

Implementando desta maneira, vai manter o seu usuário preso em um loop (`while True`), onde apenas conseguirá sair se responder uma das opções válidas, as condições de saída da função são os mesmos condicionais utilizados no if. Caso não entre em nenhum comando condicional `if` é lançada uma exceção `ValueError`.

A versão final do seu programa será:

```
import random, time
# 1 ou 4 dados de 0 a 20 numeros cada dado
def dx(x,y) :
    print("\n"+str(x) +"d"+ str(y)+" \n")
    total = 0
    time.sleep(1)
    for x in range(x):
       dado = int(random.randint(1,y))
       total = dado + total
       dado = str(dado)
       print ("Caiu : "+ dado)

    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")   
    print ("~ Total : " + str(total) + " ~" )
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

def ler_sim_ou_nao():
    while True:
        try:
            resposta = input('Deseja jogar um dado?')
            resposta = resposta.lower()
            if resposta == "sim" or resposta == "yes" or resposta == "s" or resposta =="y":
                x = random.randint(1,4)
                y = random.randint(4,20)
                dx(x,y)
                return
            elif resposta == "nao" or resposta == "no" or resposta == "n":
                print("fim da rodada")
                return
            raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Responda corretamente (sim, não, yes, no, y ou n)")

ler_sim_ou_nao()
```

Comment: opa danizavtz , poxa legal essa forma, mas a minha real duvida é entender esse while True, para tratamentos, ele é sempre assim ou existe alguma forma de eu utilizar da forma que eu estava pensando ?
`while resposta == True:`

Comment: Da maneira que estava usando creio que não entraria no while, porque o valor da variável resposta é um `str`. Aì talvez para funcionar você tivesse que fazer um cast para `boolean`.

Comment: o retorno da função `input` é sempre um valor do tipo `str`.

Comment: assim, entendi, muito obrigado!